# How to create Textview in left side and two button in right side in same line?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android lay out how to create a TextView in leftside and two button on right side with same line.
Which layout is better to use for this layout Table Or Relative ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **LinearLayout** to achieve this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="a text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923811/how-to-create-textview-in-left-side-and-two-button-in-right-side-in-same-line)thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its is better to use Relative Layout for this kind of view. use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to Align Right and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to Align Left. e.g

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#76D4F7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use a `LinearLayout` (orientation horizontal) as pointed out in the previous answer. You can also set the property under Layout Weight to 1 for each button and textview. Then set the layout width for all those object to 0. This will enable you to proportionally scale how much of the area is taken up horizontally by each object. So for example if you set the Layout Weight on the Textview to 2 and each button to 1, then the textview will take up 50% of the space horizontally (2/(2+1+1)). This makes it easier to scale the objects on different device and hopefully starts to address the question of which is the best layout to use in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923811/how-to-create-textview-in-left-side-and-two-button-in-right-side-in-same-line really helpful